# Dúvida sobre herança em classes

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, herança

Como fazer o `if` do controller retornar `TRUE` ou `FALSE` de acordo com o `check()` do Validator?

Atualmente ele retorna booleano para o `validate();`, mas eu queria que ele continuasse até o fim do código, para então retornar o booleano.

```
<?php
# relatorio venda controller
class RelatorioVendaController {
    public function __construct() {
        $form['nome'] = 'Ricardo';
        $form['idade'] = 24;

        if(RelatorioVenda::validate($form)){
            print 'Nenhum erro.';
        }
    }
}

# relatorio venda model
class RelatorioVendaModel extends RelatorioModel {
    public static function validate($form){
        $validators = array(
            "nome" => "required",
            "idade" => "required"
        );
        parent::rules($form, $validators);
    }
}

# relatorio model
class RelatorioModel {
    public static function rules($form, $validators){
        // junta os arrays foreach e executa a validacao
        Validator::check($field, $map['field'], $map['validator']);
    }
}

class Validator {
    public static function check($field, $value, $validator){
        // execute validator(field, value)

        if(no erros)
            return true;
    }
    public function required($field, $value){
        // validator
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: verifique sua função check, há um erro de sintaxe em ``if(no erros)``
**Editado**: a função ``rules`` da classe RelatorioModel precisa de um ``return`` também

Comment: acho que o correto seria `if(no errors)`

Comment: é apenas marcação, essa classe é conceitual.

Comment: Voce pode esclarecer melhor o que voce quer que o codigo faça? Eu nao entendi a parte de ir até o fim do código. Outra coisa, "orientação a objetos" não significa só ter classes e herança mas também encapsulamento, o que é perdido com as quantas funções estáticas (static). Assim é praticamente como criar funções globais. Você deveria re-organizar o código para se livrar das funções estáticas se possível.

Comment: De onde vem esse `$form` no construtor do Controller? O.o

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos De qualquer lugar, pode ser um formulário, como aqui é apenas um exemplo está implícito no código.

Comment: @JonasHartmann Quando eu chamar o RelatorioVenda::validate(), ele executa essa função e retorna boleano de acordo com aquele escopo. Gostaria que ele seguisse o "parent::rules($form, $validators)" e dependendo do resultado de lá, ele retorna lá no controller. Fica meio confuso de explicar, mas conseguiu entender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar uma **`variável`**!

```
    $booleano = RelatorioVenda::validate($form);
    if($booleano){
        print 'Nenhum erro.';
    }
    return $booleano;
```

Não esqueça de usar **`return`** para que as funções retornem algum resultado...

... mas lembre-se que a chamada indireta a um construtor via operador **new** retorna sempre **uma nova instância de uma classe**, e nunca um *booleano* ou qualquer outro tipo de resultado.

Portanto você deve mover essa parte do seu código para um outro método da classe.

Comment: Na verdade, `__construct` não retorna nada. Não deve haver uma declaração `return` no corpo do construtor.

Comment: Está errado dizer que `__construct` não retorna nada: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11904285/370290 - embora, evidentemente esse uso seja completamente inadequado.

Comment: De qualquer maneira, melhorei o enunciado na minha resposta baseado no seu *feedback*. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Lembre-se que construtores NÃO POSSUEM RETORNO.

O melhor jeito de fazer o que você pretende é através de exceções:

```
# relatorio venda controller
class RelatorioVendaController {
    public function __construct($form) { //editei essa linha pra fazer sentido
        $form['nome'] = 'Ricardo';
        $form['idade'] = 24;

        if(RelatorioVenda::validate($form)){
            print 'Nenhum erro.';
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Houve algum erro de validação');
        }
    }
}
```

Na hora de usar, você faz:

```
try {
    $controller = new RelatorioVendaController($form); // seja lá de onde vem esse $form;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // tome as providências necessárias
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21099742/370290

Comment: Só porque É POSSÍVEL FAZER, não quer dizer que se DEVA fazer.

Comment: Com certeza. Igual fumar ou comer carne.